# Autosize to parent

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have this simple example. I want to autosize the chart to fill the parent.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        flowPane.getChildren().addAll(test());
        flowPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        flowPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        //flowPane.setPrefWidth(1200);
        flowPane.setVgap(4);
        flowPane.setHgap(4);
        flowPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
        scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroll.setContent(flowPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(scroll, 1500, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private AreaChart<String, Number> test()
    {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        final AreaChart<String, Number> sc = new AreaChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        sc.setAnimated(false);  // Turn off chart animation during first appearance

        sc.setCreateSymbols(false);

        sc.setPrefSize(1200, 210);

        return sc;
    }
```

How I can auto size the chart to fill always the parent size? Is there some simple solution without binding?

Can you propose some solution?

Comment: Is there any good reason for you to use `FlowPane`? Because if you use `StackPane` instead it automatically resizes to fill parent size

Comment: Yes, this is one solution. Can you propose something else because I have may children and I need to add gap between them.

Comment: Can you show an example? Because if there would be some other child in `FlowPane`, then `Chart` cannot use full size of the parent.

Comment: If you just need to add some insets, then `StackPane` can do that too. `stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));` would result in that http://i.imgur.com/nNmuWIA.png

Answer (score 0):

So, since you want to fill whole parent with only one graph anyway, I don't think there's any good reason to use `FlowPane`for that. It would be better to use `StackPane` instead

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    AreaChart<String, Number> chart = test();
    StackPane.setAlignment(chart, Pos.CENTER);
    stackPane.getChildren().add(chart);
    stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");

//  FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
//
//  flowPane.getChildren().addAll(test());
//  flowPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
//  flowPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
//  //flowPane.setPrefWidth(1200);
//  flowPane.setVgap(4);
//  flowPane.setHgap(4);
//  flowPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
    scroll.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
    scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
    scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
    scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
    scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
//  scroll.setContent(flowPane);
    scroll.setContent(stackPane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(scroll, 1500, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

However if you really want to use FlowPane, then you could use binding. In your case it's very easy. It's just simple 2 lines of code

```
    chart.prefWidthProperty().bind(flowPane.widthProperty().subtract(10)); //substract 10 because of 5px insets on each side
    chart.prefHeightProperty().bind(flowPane.heightProperty().subtract(10)); //same here
```

Here you just say that preferred width and height of `chart` would always be equal to width and height of `flowPane` minus 10 (because of your insets)

Comment: I tested this solution but I have 12 charts. They are one ever another. I need to add another layer maybe?